# Python Protocols: cannot understand 'class objects vs protocols"

Tags: python, typing, pep

I'm reading PEP 544, specifically the [section for class objects vs protocols](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#type-and-class-objects-vs-protocols), and I cannot understand the last example given there, I'll copy paste it here:

> A class object is considered an implementation of a protocol if accessing all members on it results in types compatible with the protocol members. For example:

```py
from typing import Any, Protocol

class ProtoA(Protocol):
    def meth(self, x: int) -> int: ...
class ProtoB(Protocol):
    def meth(self, obj: Any, x: int) -> int: ...

class C:
    def meth(self, x: int) -> int: ...

a: ProtoA = C  # Type check error, signatures don't match!
b: ProtoB = C  # OK
```

I can get the rest of the PEP, but this example seems counterintuitive to me. The way I would think it is that the class `C` implements the method `meth` with the same signature as `ProtoA`, so why the heck is an error in line `a: ProtoA = C`?

And why `b: ProtoB = C` is correct? The signature of `C.meth` is different than the signature of `ProtoB.meth` (the latter includes an extra argument `obj: Any`.

Can someone explain this by expanding the concept so I can understand it?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me, either.  I think those two comments should be swapped.

Comment: Agreed. I submitted a pull request to fix it

Comment: @chepner can you share the pull request link? I would love to read it

Comment: Sure. It's pretty boring, though :) https://github.com/chepner/peps/pull/1.

Comment: Ok, I found a PR (not sure if chepners) for it and from the comments I now get it, I'll put an answer myself tomorrow.

Comment: Sigh, my pull request is to merge into my own fork, not the upstream.

Comment: OK, https://github.com/python/peps/pull/3010 should be more correct.

Comment: Pull request rejected, but I think I understand why. (Not enough to provide a good answer, but enough to accept the reasoning.) The issue here is that we aren't considering `C` to be a *subclass* of `ProtoA` or `ProtoB`, but if the class object `C` itself can be used to call `C.meth(1)` or `C.meth(some_object, 1)`. It's the former that's not allowed, while the latter is legal (though `some_object` itself almost certainly must be an instance of `C`, and you would typically write `some_object.meth(1)` instead).

Comment: @chepner yes, I understand the same now, it's about if the class `C` itself fulfills the promise made by `ProtoA` or `ProtoB` (i.e., if `C` is an implementation of `ProtoA` or of `ProtoB`). I just put an answer, feel free to comment on it if something is off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussing a bit in the question comments and checking [a pull request addressing the example of the question](https://github.com/python/peps/pull/2332) I can understand now why the example is correct and where my reasoning was off. Here it goes:

### Typical case: checking an instance against a Protocol

Let's expand the example a bit to consider the more common case of checking if an instance of `C` is an implementation of `ProtoA` or `ProtoB`:

```py
c: ProtoA = C()  # OK
c: ProtoB = C()  # Type check error, signature don't match!
```

So, clearly, and as expected, an instance of `C` is an implementation of `ProtoA` because the promise of `ProtoA` is that any implementation of it will have a method `meth` that can be called as `c.meth(2)` (`2` can be any other integer in this case), and I can clearly do:

```py
c.meth(2)  # This is correct according to the signature/type hints.
```

### Given case: checking a class against a Protocol

So, what happens in the given example? What happens is that `C` has a method `meth` but it's not defined as a class method, so, `C.meth` has a different signature than `c.meth`, in fact, `C.meth` has the signature that is promised by `ProtoB`, and not by `ProtoA`, because to use `C.meth` directly from the class, I need to pass an argument to satisfy `self`, which has implicit type `Any`:

```py
# This...
c = C()
c.meth(2)
# ...is equivalent to this.
c = C()
C.meth(c, 2)

# But the promise is fulfilled with anything as first argument
# because there is no explicit type hint for `self` and thus it is
# implicityly typed as `Any`.
C.meth('anything is fine here', 2)  # this is a correct call*

# *although it might result in an error depending on the implementation 
# if the `self` argument had runtime requirements not expressed in the 
# type hint.
```

So there it is, it had a simple explanation after all.